# Reference request - Nomenclature of organophosphorus compounds?

Tags: nomenclature, reference-request, organophosphorus-compounds

Can someone please provide me a good reference for the nomenclature of organophosphorus compounds such as pesticides and chemical warfare agents? Something from the IUPAC would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual substitutive nomenclature for organic compounds was extended to various other elements including phosphorus. The current rules for name construction of organic compounds containing phosphorus are included in *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001).* These recommendations cover typical organophosphorus compounds that are used as pesticides and chemical warfare agents. However, they do not include the nomenclature for organometallic compounds, coordination compounds, polymers, and some natural products.